# How to check if a response is correct?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I want to create a tailor-made feedback sheet for my pupils depending on their answers to questions on a Google Form.

When iterating through ItemResponses from a Form response using the following code:

```
function response_deal() {
      var form = FormApp.openById('bla');
     var formResponses = form.getResponses();
     for (var i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++) {
     var formResponse = formResponses[i];
     var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
     for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
     var itemResponse = itemResponses[j];
     Logger.log('Response #%s to the question "%s" was "%s" and the score was "%s"',
     (i + 1).toString(),
     itemResponse.getItem().getTitle(),
     itemResponse.getResponse(),
     itemResponse.getScore()  );
     }
     }

     }
```

I need some code that will check whether the itemResponse is correct 
e.g.

```
if itemResponse.isCorrect()
```

or similar.

Does anyone know of there is a suitable method for this?

One technique I tried is to use the:

```
 itemResponse.getScore()
```

method but this returns null even if I setScore(1) etc. unless I allow the assignment to be graded and release a points score, which I don't want to do.

Comment: Unless it's a quiz it's just a form with no concept of right or wrong. You can keep a Spreadsheet with a reference and cross check for each question id if the reference value matches the answer

Comment: It is a quiz. That is certainly a solution but I wonder if there's a more elegant way?

Comment: No, there is not. The itemResponse comes directly from the getItemResponses method of the form object. So you cannot add a method to that object. I would follow @RobinGertenbach suggestion.

Comment: Robin, would you briefly be able to describe the data structure of the spreadsheet?